# How can I prevent negative time in using military time format

Tags: c#, timespan

when my starttime = "19:00" PM then my endtime ="01:30" AM
the answer is negative , how can i prevent negative result in time?

```
string startime = record.TimeStart;
string endtime = record.TimeFinish;
TimeSpan span = DateTime.Parse(endtime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startime));
string hours_spent = string.Format(
    "{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", 
    span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
```

Comment: I dont have proper DateTime to use because i get the data in my Custom Data set , I set it a as string , can i set up it with DateTime? but thanks with your comment! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one day to `endtime` if it (or more precisely, its time component) is earlier than `starttime`'s. Something like this:

```
var startDateTime = DateTime.Parse(starttime).Time;
var endDateTime = DateTime.Parse(endtime).Time;
if (endDateTime < startDateTime)
{
    endDateTime += TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
}
TimeSpan timeSpent = endDateTime - startDateTime;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are crossing midnight, so the *actual* comparison is (using today's date as an example):

```
[2015-10-12 01:30]  - [2015-10-12 19:00]
```

which is `-17 hrs and 30 minutes`.  If you want to convert that to a positive time then either add a date component or add 24 hours to the time span:

```
if(span.Hours < 0)
   span = span.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: Would you consider it bad form to compare the span with the Zero static member provided by Timespan instead?

Comment: @Ben: Making use of `Zero` appears to be semantically more correct than having to use the `Hours` property IMHO.

Comment: by the way i cant use AddDays in span. but thanks to your answer in my question ! :)